# How to retrieve output data as JSON from IBM Watson cloud

Tags: json, ibm-watson, docplex, docplexcloud

I am solving a **decision optimization problem** using Cplex solver (Docplex) on **IBM Watson Cloud**. However, I got stuck trying to adapt the **output format**.

Available documentation provides the following function to include in the main file in order to retrieve the output as a **.csv file**:

```
def write_all_outputs(outputs):
    '''Write all dataframes in ``outputs`` as .csv.

    Args:
        outputs: The map of outputs 'outputname' -> 'output df'
    '''
    for (name, df) in iteritems(outputs):
        csv_file = '%s.csv' % name
        print(csv_file)
        with get_environment().get_output_stream(csv_file) as fp:
            if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
                fp.write(df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf8'))
            else:
                fp.write(df.to_csv(index=False).encode(encoding='utf8'))
    if len(outputs) == 0:
        print("Warning: no outputs written")
```

Then in the **deployment**, the file type is specified :

```
solve_payload = {
      
        client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.OUTPUT_DATA: [
            {
                "id" : ".*\.csv"
            }
        ]
    }
```

All works fine with .csv files.

However, I would like to get a **.json file** instead. I have therefore created the corresponding dictionary and modified the function as follows:

```
def write_all_outputs(outputs):
    for (name, content) in iteritems(outputs):
        json_file = '%s.json' % name
        with get_environment().get_output_stream(json_file) as fp:
            fp.write(json.dumps({name: content}).encode('utf-8'))
    if len(outputs) == 0:
        print("Warning: no outputs written")
```

And also in the deployment:

```
solve_payload = {
        client.deployments.DecisionOptimizationMetaNames.OUTPUT_DATA: [
            {
                "id" : ".*\.json"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem is **solved normally** (to optimality). The issue is that I get a **weird .JSON file** content with random letters. I suspect there is something wrong with the **write_all_outputs** function. Note that **running locally produces a proper .JSON file** with no issues.

I would really appreciate any help regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those encountering the same issue. I got an answer on IBM forum.

*With inlined output data, everything except CSV files are base64 encoded.
So you need to get the content of the json from the job details and decode it.*

*For example, with log.txt, it it:*

```
    import base64
    import io
    
    output_data = job_details['entity']['decision_optimization']['output_data']
    
    logs = [line for o in output_data if o['id'] == 'log.txt' for line in io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(o['content']))]
    for l in logs:
        print(l)
```